# How to write belongs_to association when the foreign key can refer to either of two different columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`cars.dealership_id` can either refer to `dealerships.id` or `dealerships.remote_id`. How should I write my associations?

**SCHEMA**

```rb
create_table "cars", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", limit: 255, null: false
    t.integer "dealership_id", null: false
end

create_table "dealerships", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", limit: 255, null: false
  t.integer "remote_id", null: true
end
```

**MODEL**

```rb
class Car < ::ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dealership,
    class_name: '::Dealership',
    foreign_key: :dealership_id,
    primary_key: :remote_id

  belongs_to :dealership,
    class_name: '::Dealership',
    foreign_key: :dealership_id,
    primary_key: :id
end
```

Comment: Would this question be more clear if you renamed the `dealerships.dealership_id` column to `remote_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `cars.dealership_id` can either refer to `dealerships.id` or `dealerships.remote_id`.

I'd suggest this design is problematic, and I'd recommend changing your database design as follows:

```sql
alter table cars
add constraint fk_cars_dealerships
foreign key (dealership_id)
references dealerships (id)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
;
```

With this change, the association becomes clear.

```rb
belongs_to :dealership
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, create_table will create a primary key called id. You can change the name of the primary key with the :primary_key option (don’t forget to update the corresponding model) or, if you don’t want a primary key at all, you can pass the option id: false.

For creating primary key other than ID you can use the following.

```
class CreateContentUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :content_units, primary_key: :guoid do |t|
      t.boolean :active, default: false
    end
  end
end
```

So now `guoid` will be used as primary key and now you can use your API `ID` as id in the model